# jquery - Cannot execute action on added elements (added on the run using jquery)

Tags: jquery

My idea is to create a button that show multiple text, and when i click on that text, it will be added in the textbox

My code for showing multiple text that suitable :

```
$("#btnLook").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
   ...
        success: function(data1) {
        for( var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++ )
            {
            var spn = '<span class ="spnSuggestion" id="data1[' + i + ']">' + data1[i] + '</span>'; 
            $("#divSuggestion").html($("#divSuggestion").html() + '  ' + spn);
            }
        },
   ...
  });
```

and then this function is for clicking the text

```
  $(".spnSuggestion").click(function(){
    alert ("A");
```

But this code is not running, and not showing any alert box, any solution please

Comment: is it an object literal or an array literal? We're going to need to see the response data.

Comment: What you get `alert(data1);` outside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".spnSuggestion")` returns all elements that match the selector *when you call it*. It does not account for any new elements.

To account for new elements, use event delegation:

```
$('#divSuggestion').on('click', '.spnSuggestion', function() {
    ...
});
```

Also, don't abuse `.html()`. Make a jQuery object and append it:

```
$('<span class ="spnSuggestion" id="data1[' + i + ']">' + data1[i] + '</span>').appendTo('#divSuggestion');
```

Or:

```
$('<span>', {
    'class': 'spnSuggestion',
    'id': 'data1[' + i + ']',
    'text': data1[i]
}).appendTo('#divSuggestion');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', '.spnSuggestion', function(){
    alert ("A");
}
```

This applies the click event to the body element (you can use any jQuery selector to use any element higher up the DOM tree) but only fires it for `.spnSuggestion` elements. It will work for dynamically added elements.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
 $(".spnSuggestion").live('click',function(){
  alert ("A");
```

because your element is creating in runtime and .click runs on document ready.

Comment: `.live`'s been gone for a while now.